# Wann soll ich den Konjunktiv I benutzen, und wann soll ich "soll" benutzen, um indirekte Rede anzugeben?

Tags: subjunctive, writing, indirect-speech

Hier ist ein Beispiel davon, was ich meine:

In einer Hausarbeit rede ich von den Kritiken eines Buchs. 
Angenommen, dass eine lautet: 
*"Das Buch vermeidet oft die Frage der deutschen Schuldproblematik."*, welcher der folgenden Sätze wäre richtig?

> "Um es überhaupt zu wissen, ob das Buch die Schuldproblematik
>    ***vermeiden soll*..."**
>   "Um es überhaupt zu wissen, ob das Buch die Schuldproblematik
>    ***vermeide*..."**

Oder in einem ähnlichen Kontext, aber in der Vergangenheit, 
ob etwas ***passiert sein soll*, oder es *passiert sei***.

Ich weiß, dass ich auch einfach *vermeidet* oder *passierte* schreiben kann, aber ich will auch eine Menge Zweifel säen.

Danke für die Hilfe.

Comment: Nur als Hinweis: eigentlich vermeidet das Buch nichts, sondern der die Autor/in. Dennoch sagen es manche. Soll die Ansicht von Kritiker x in Zweifel gezogen werden, braucht es danach eine argumentative Auseinandersetzung mit dem Buch oder andere zitierte Kritiker. Der Beispielsatz mit "Um überhaupt ... vermeide/ vermeidet..:" müsste danach die selbst ermittelten Buchaussagen mit der Einschätzung des Kritikers vergleichen. Ansonsten ist es Polemik und keine Wissenschaft. Und Zweifel "säe" ich nur nüchtern mit Zitaten und Argumenten. Kein "na ihr wisst schon".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Soll" kannst du in dem von dir angeführten Kontext überhaupt nicht verwenden.

#### Verwendungsarten von "soll"

"Soll" kann in zwei Bedeutungen eingesetzt werden:

1) (Moralische) Verpflichtung

> Du sollst nicht töten.
>
> Du solltest mal dein Zimmer aufräumen.

2) Distanzierung des Sprechers von einer Aussage

> Die Amerikaner sollen gar nicht auf den Mond geflogen sein.
>
> Hitler soll gar nicht 1945 gestorben sein.
>
> Fritz soll was mit Maria haben.

Das heißt hier: Jemand sagt das, aber ich (als Sprecher) mache mir die Behauptung nicht zueigen.

#### Dein Beispielsatz richtig formuliert

Der Satz in deinem Beispiel heißt grammatisch richtig und stilistisch gut:

> Um zu wissen, ob das Buch die Schuldproblematik vermeidet, müsste man es erst einmal lesen.
>
> Um festzustellen, ob das Buch die Schuldproblematik vermeidet, muss man es Kapitel für Kapitel analysieren.

(Ich verwende verschiedene Variationen mit Konjunktiv und Indikativ sowie mit verschiedenen Verben, nur um dir die Möglichkeiten zu zeigen, die man hat.)

#### "Soll" in deinem Beispielsatz

Du könntstest nun natürlich - rein theoretisch - hergehen und einen Satz bilden wie:

> Um festzustellen, ob das Buch die Schuldproblematik vermeiden **soll**, muss man es Kapitel für Kapitel lesen.

Damit sagst du aber etwas anderes! Du sagst damit explizit, dass du vermutest, dass der Autor in dem Buch ganz bewusst anstrebt, die Schuldproblematik als Thema auszulassen. Diese wäre aber eine Verwendung von "soll" im Sinne einer Verpflichtung: Das Buch ist (vom Autor) "verpflichtet" oder "beauftragt", das Thema zu umgehen. Oder mit anderen Worten: Der Autor plant, in dem Buch allerlei Themen anzusprechen, das Thema "Schuld" jedoch wegzulassen. - Das ist also eine sehr spezielle Bedeutung, und du hattest diese vermutlich nicht im Sinn.

Um die Sache mit "das Buch soll [etwas tun oder nicht tun]" einmal auf die Spitze zu treiben: Wenn du ausdrücken willst:

> Jemand sagt, dass der Autor will, dass das Buch das Thema auslässt.

Dann könntest du theoretisch sagen:

> Was ich so gehört habe, soll das Buch das Thema auslassen sollen.

In diesem Satz wird "sollen" zuerst im Sinne "Distanzierung", dann im Sinne "Verpflichtung" verwendet. Das ist nun aber eine so komplizierte Situation, dass kein Mensch sich je so ausdrücken würde. Natürlicher klänge:

> Was ich so gehört habe, soll Paul was mit Maria anfangen wollen.

Oder:

> Paul soll was mit Maria anfangen wollen.

(Diese Sätze nur zum Beweis, dass sie syntaktisch funktionieren.)

Mit anderen Worten:

> Jemand hat gesagt, dass Paul etwas mit Maria anfangen möchte.

#### In der Vergangenheit

Nun zu Formen der Vergangenheit (sei passiert, soll passiert sein):

Wenn du sagst:

> Ich habe gehört, dass die Amerikaner auf den Mond geflogen sein sollen.

dann distanzierst du dich von der Aussage "Die Amerikaner sind auf den Mond geflogen". Du sagst nicht, dass du sie für falsch  hältst, du sagst aber auch nicht, dass du sie für wahr hältst. Du sagst, dass du die Behauptung gehört hast und dass du persönlich nicht dabei warst, um die Richtigkeit der Behauptung einschätzen zu können.

Man kann allerdings argumentieren, dass jemand, der eine so allgemein bekannte Tatsache in einen "soll"-Satz packt, eben doch Zweifel an der Behauptung ausdrücken will. Es kommt hier stark auf den Kontext an.

Wenn du sagst:

> Desoxyribonukleinsäure soll bei Kontakt mit freien Radikalen anfällig für Substratbildung sein.

dann wird der Hörer oder Leser nicht annehmen, dass du die Aussage anzweifelst (wie bei der Mondlandung), sondern nur, dass du dir selbst eine Beurteilung des Wahrheitsgehalts der Aussage nicht zutraust.

#### Konjunktiv für indirekte Rede

Du kannst sagen:

> Alle ernstzunehmenden Quellen sagen, dass die Amerikaner in den 1960er Jahren auf dem Mond gelandet **seien**. Besonders in Social-Media-Publikationen wird hingegen häufig die These vertreten, dass sie dort nie wirklich hingeflogen **seien** und die Mondlandung nur in einem Filmstudio inszeniert **hätten**.

Hier drückst du in einem gehobenen (wissenschaftlichen) Sprachstil deine (zumindest technische) Neutralität in der Frage "Hat die Mondlandung stattgefunden?" aus.

Genau das gleiche, aber in etwas alltagsnäherer Ausdrucksweise sagst du mit:

> Alle ernstzunehmenden Quellen sagen, dass die Amerikaner in den 1960er Jahren auf dem Mond gelandet **sind**. Besonders in Social-Media-Publikationen wird hingegen häufig die These vertreten, dass sie dort nie wirklich hingeflogen **sind** und die Mondlandung nur in einem Filmstudio inszeniert **haben**.

(So kannst du dich mündlich problemlos ausdrücken. Schreiben solltest du so nicht.)

#### Tatsachen vs. Behauptungen

Dein Vorschlag

> Um festzustellen, ob das Buch das Thema x **vermeide**...

(also mit Konjunktiv) funktioniert gar nicht. Das hat einen logischen Grund: "wissen" oder "feststellen" beziehen sich auf jeden Fall auf Fakten. Darum musst du hier Indikativ verwenden. Konjunktiv würde dort passen, wo es um Meinungen und Auffassungen geht.

> Zu behaupten, dass das Buch das Thema vermeide, ist eine Unverschämtheit gegenüber dem Autor.

Hier wird Konjunktiv verwendet, weil es nicht um die **Tatsache** des Vermeidens oder Nichtvermeidens geht, sondern um die **Behauptung** des Vermeidens oder Nichtvermeidens.

Zum Spaß hier noch ein Behauptung (im Konjunktiv) in einer Behauptung (im Konjunktiv) also praktisch wie in einer russischen Puppe:

> Sie sagte, zu behaupten, dass das Buch das Thema vermeide, sei eine Unverschämtheit.

Oder mit drei Stufen:

> Er gab an, sie habe gesagt, zu behaupten, dass das Buch das Thema vermeide, sei eine Unverschämtheit.